# Increase buffer for Apple WatchOS sysdiagnose

Tags: apple-watch, sysdiagnose

I am taking a trace of Apple Workouts outdoor workout session to see the GPS data on an Apple Watch and the sysdiagnose file only shows the last 10 minutes. Is there a way to increase the buffer size to 30 minutes so I can read the entirety of longer workout sessions?